# Haystack login required

Tags: django-haystack

I am using Haystack default URLConf to setup the views. As such:

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

How would I wrap it in a login_required decorator, since I only want logged in users to access the search. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in root **urls.py** add

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from haystack.views import basic_search
```

and change:

```
url(r'search/*', include(haystack.urls)),
```

to the following line:

```
url(r'search/$', login_required(basic_search), name='basic_search'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't wrap a URL inclusion with the `login_required` decorator.

What you should do is either add some middleware for just that URL path or explicitly add your search view. The default `urls.py` configuration only defines one URL:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.views import SearchView


urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', SearchView(), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

So in your own URLs configuration you could import the `SearchView` (probably a good idea if you want to configure at all) and then wrap that view. In your own `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', login_required(SearchView()), name='haystack_search'),
)
```